# Google Analytics, Adsense, WordPress, There is more traffic on website then it shows in google analtycis

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, adsense

I am not sure what's the issue is.

But I believe I have more traffic on my website then it show in google analytics, even my adsense earning drop down.

I have change whatever I searched on the Internet. I have created new .htaccess file, have added new wp-admin and wp-include folder on my server, I have change Analytics code location, (header, Footer).

I have attached my yesterday traffic. and have attached the Property Hit Volume screen shot too. in chart it shows 2,667 but in Property Hit Volume it shows last day hits are 5,979.

Why the both hits are not same? I haven't added any filter on analytics.

[image: Image Attached]

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics has a real-time feature.  In other words, when you visit a web page, you should be able to see your visit immediately.  Within your Analytics account, navigate to Real-Time | Content.  Each time you visit one of your pages you should see that page and your visit appear in the time sweep.  Of course if others are visiting your website they will appear as well.

What you are looking for is a page or pages where the Analytics tracking is not working.  It might relate to a Wordpress page template lacking the tracking code, although in many Wordpress sites, there is a specific menu feature to insert the Google Analytics code on all pages.

If all your pages are reporting the visit, I would double check the location of the tracking code.  I believe Google recommends placing the code right after the opening  tag, but often I place it just before the closing  tag without issue.  But depending on site functionality, the position of the tracking code may affect the results depending on how the page loads.

Another possibility is that your website is been scanned and the bot is terminating the request before your Google Analytics tracking code fires.

If not of these ideas help, you can always call Google (800-919-9922) and ask for their help.  If you are outside of North America, I'm not sure if that phone number will work.